# Embedded Matlab - testing for bottlenecks

Tags: matlab

I have an embedded Matlab function that itself calls other embedded Matlab functions and which also calls mex functions.  Where can I find information about how to test blocks of this code for the time it takes to execute?  Ideally there is something like `tic` `toc` that I can stick before and after a block in order to determine how long it takes to execute.  And perhaps `tic` `toc` even works, but I don't know if I should trust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in profiler:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html

Comment: I'm still checking in to this, but I don't think the profiler can be made to work in Embedded Matlab and in Mex.

Comment: You should be able to use the profiler with mex. Search for mex in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/29489/2/content/AlgoTrading2010/html/AlgoTradingDemo5.html